# Select Knowledge object in SOQL query

Tags: apex, soql, query, knowledge

I'm trying to get all articles which are published and online. 
In my user I turned on all permission set and so one to have access to Knowledge.

```
List<Knowledge__kav> myList= [SELECT Id, KnowledgeArticleId, PublishStatus, Language, Title, Summary, ArticleNumber, ArticleType, ArticleBody__c FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE PublishStatus='Online'];
```

Above is my query, but in log i got sth like this.

> sObject type 'Knowledge__kav' is not supported.

Can somebody know how to get all object of this type in Apex class ?

Comment: Have you enabled `Knowledge User` checkbox in your user who executing this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowledge can be a bit confusing to query. I don't believe querying knowledge directly is supported. However, you can query the knowledge articles per article type. For instance, if your article type is called `Offer`, you can query it like:

```
SELECT Title
FROM Offer__kav
WHERE PublishStatus='online'
```

Comment: N.B. see [schema](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_knowledge.htm?search_text=knowledge). There is no Knowledge SObject

Comment: I think there is an Knowledge sObject, just no object, or if there is an object for it then we can't query it. Otherwise the the error message shouldn't be: sObject type 'Knowledge__kav' is not supported

Comment: right, I was sloppy - I meant Object :-)

Comment: Yeah but when i try assigne it to list (List<sObject> or List<Object> or List<Knowledge__kav>) it doesnt work. So how i should assigne my query to list of some types of object ?

Comment: Classic Knowledge types have one object per Article type, i.e., FAQ__kav and Tips__kav. Lightning Knowledge has one Object type, Knowlege__kav, and would have two record types representing the two Article types.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was that i havn not permission set on this article type. So if someone in future will have same issue this is the fix.

Comment: This answer would be more likely to help future visitors if you **[edit]** its content to specify how you check/manipulate this permission.